# Too much time for spell checking in python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spell-checking, lemmatization

I have a dataframe with around 200,000 rows and each line has approximetely 30 tokenized words. I am trying to fix spelling mistakes, then lemmatize them.

Some words are not in the dictionary so, if the frequency of them is too high, I just pass that word, if not, I correct it.

```
spell = SpellChecker() 
def spelling_mistake_corrector(word):
    checkedWord = spell.correction(word)
    if freqDist[checkedWord] >= freqDist[word]:
    word = checkedWord
return word

def correctorForAll(text):
    text = [spelling_mistake_corrector(word) for word in text]
    return text

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
def lemmatize_words(text):
    text = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in text]
    text = [word for word in text if len(word) > 2] #filtering 1 and 2 letter words out
    return text

def apply_corrector_and_lemmatizer(text):
    return lemmatize_words(correctorForAll(text))

df['tokenized'] = df['tokenized'].apply(apply_corrector_and_lemmatizer)
```

The thing is: this code is running on colab for 3 hours, what should I do to improve run time? Thanks!

Comment: If the code works this should probably be on codereview not SO

Comment: `lemmatizing` and `spell checking` are expensive operations. You may speed up your code a little bit by making some changes, even though time complexity will not change.. First, you are iterating twice on each text. There are two list comprehensions, are they really necessary? Can't you do it all in one loop? In addition, you are using `.apply` which is likely more expensive than a list comprehension itself for non-vectorized operations. Since operations are independent, you may consider to parallelize your operations across multiple cores

Comment: Thanks for the reply, only lemmatization takes 40 seconds for whole dataframe. I was not expecting `spell checking` to require that much time.